# R - Divide data in a single column to multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I divide the data in a single column to multiple columns

```
[10,
 11,
 12,
 13,
 14,
 15,
 .
 .
 .
]
```

Now I ant to divide this data into multiple columns like this and assign column values

```
[a,b,c
 10,11,12
 13,14,15
 16,17,18
.,.,.,
.,.,.,
.,.,.,]
```

How can I do this R.

Comment: `matrix(data, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a column, we can change it to `matrix` by

```
matrix(df1$v1, ncol = 3, byrow=TRUE)
```

or use the `dim`

```
m1 <- df1$v1
dim(m1) <- c(10, 3) #dimension depends on the length of column
```

Comment: How to assign column names?

Comment: @JackDaniel  You can use the `dimnames` argument in `matrix` i.e. `matrix(df1$v1, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("V", 1:3)))`